# Change the basemap background color from white to black in arcgis js api?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, basemap

I have a **basemap** layer that I published and placed on my application and this layer has a number of blank areas that shows up as white areas since the background of the layer itself is white.

Is there any way of changing this to a different color such as black?

I tried changing the data frame color before publishing the layer however this had no impact on the application itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple , Just Add a line of css in your webApp in which you change the background of the map div container :

if you're using js api 2.x-3.x :

```
#map_root {
  background-color:black;
}
```

if you're using js api 4.x :

```
.esri-view-root {
  background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick thanks! As for some reason the color wasn't being changed for be in map initialization in the js file.